# How can I find the maximum value of one variable, conditional on the level of another?

Tags: r, max

I have a vector of hourly temperatures (`DATA$TEMP`) linked to dates (`DATA$DATE`) and thermometer position (`DATA$PLACE`).

I want identify the maximum temperature conditional on date and position. I can easily do this one date and position at a time, given I specify each date and position.  eg.

```
x <- max(DATA$TEMP[DATA$DATE =="20/12/15" & DATA$PLACE=="room"])
```

However I have many dates and positions and would like a function that can run through each date / position combination and return a vector of max temps linked to each.

Comment: Did you do any search effort?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
library(dplyr)

x <- DATA %>% 
   group_by(DATE, PLACE) %>%                 
   summarise(maximum= max(TEMP))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here an answer using `base`:

```
 by(DATA$TEMP, list(DATA$DATE, DATA$PLACE), max)
```

On a more general note, this kind of problem falls under the `split-apply-combine` paradigm. If you google this, you will find that there are quite many ways of doing this in R. From several `base` functions, to `plyr`, `dplyr`, and `data.table` versions. See e.g. [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/a-quick-primer-on-split-apply-combine-problems/).

Answer (score 0):

Another option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DATA)[, list(Max = max(TEMP)) , .(DATE, PLACE)]
```

---

Or with `base R` `aggregate`

```
aggregate(TEMP~DATE+PLACE, DATA, FUN= max)
```